# How to create java level caching at server side

Tags: java, caching

I am trying to cache the database objects into Java objects at server side whenever server is going to startup.

At present I am just using static Hashmap to set the property at startup and update the property whenever user update the value from GUI. It is very difficult to maintain caching functionalities whenever updating the value.

Can any one please help me to apply caching functionalities at server side in java?

Comment: use `ehcache` Its very easy to configure and can go good with other frameworks like spring and hibernate. http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples

Answer (score 2):

Ehcache is one of the best approaches. It comes with a default configuration to make it up and use in application in minutes.

`CacheManager.getInstance().addCache("test");` will create a cache with name test and defualt properties.

Adding an object will be easy you need to create an `net.sf.ehcache.Element` with key and value and put it in cache.
`CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("test").put(new Element(key, value));`

Then fetching back from cache is also similar you just need to `get(key);`.

If you have spring in your application, your life is even simpler. You can add `@Cacheble` annotation on a method to cache the return value. You can find lot help from spring documentation.

By default the configuration will have 120 secs of expiry time. That means what ever objects you put into cache will expire and removed after 120 secs. You can increase/tweak this by having your own cache.xml.

Answer (score 1):

For simple caching you can use ehcache. If JPA implementation is based on Hibernate, infinispan is the right choice. Distributed caching is better in infinispan compared to ehcache as it can be run as an individual process (infinispan Hot Rod Server).